# Return same row multiple times for each value in an array-based column

Tags: sql, arrays, postgresql

Say I have a table with an array column:

```
id | subIds
1  | {1,2,3}
2  | {4,5}
```

How would I return the resultset:

```
id | subId    
1  | 1
1  | 2
1  | 3
2  | 4
2  | 5
```

... in a single query without using a function?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

By "*without using a function*" I assume you mean "*without **writing my own function** to do it*".

The `unnest()` function will do what you want

```
select id, unnest(subids) as subid
from the_table;
```

The order on how the elements are returned is undefined though.

Comment: Thank you. Your assumption is correct. Fortunately the order isn't important but I assume an 'ORDER BY' clause would work if it was?

Comment: @SpliFF: yes that would work. I was referring to the order in which the elements from the array are returned. Though in reality they are always returned in the order they were stored in the array - but you can't rely on that. The upcoming Postgres 9.4 will have `with ordinality` which gives you better control over that.